# Transform XML Attributes to Tags ( Nodes ) without using XSLT in Java

Tags: java, xml, attributes, transform

I have two XMLs - One has Tags and other has those tags as attributes and values.  I need to merge the two xmls.  I need to do it using Java without using xslt. I will have different pairs of xmls that I will need to merge, so I want to write a generic program to do it.  How do I go about it?  All the examples I found are using XSLT.

**Update : Added Example**

Sample Input 1 - XML As Nodes

```
<PROPERTIES>
    <PROPERTY>
        <ADDRESS>
            <AddressLineText></AddressLineText>
            <CityName></CityName>
            <PostalCode></PostalCode>
            <StateCode></StateCode>
        </ADDRESS>
    </PROPERTY>
</PROPERTIES>
```

*Sample Input 2 - XML As Attributes*

```
    <DocData DescriptorID="95" Value="70056" Name="PostalCode"/>
    <DocData DescriptorID="81" Value="LA" Name="StateCode"/>
    <DocData DescriptorID="15" Value="GRETNA" Name="CityName"/>
    <DocData DescriptorID="49" Value="721 SAMPLE DR" Name="AddressLineText"/>
```

Sample Expected Output

```
<PROPERTIES>
    <PROPERTY>
        <ADDRESS>
            <AddressLineText>721 SAMPLE DR</AddressLineText>
            <CityName>GRETNA</CityName>
            <PostalCode>70056</PostalCode>
            <StateCode>LA</StateCode>
        </ADDRESS>
    </PROPERTY>
</PROPERTIES>
```

What I want to do is - merge the above two XMLs - and update the values from the attributes as text value for the matching nodes.   For that, I thought I should first convert the XML with attributes to XML with nodes and then try the merge.

If you have any other suggestion, I would like to try that.

Since the Tag information is not the same in all pairs I need to do it for, I want to avoid xsl.

Thanks

Comment: what is it about xslt that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: I haven't used xslt before, but I think, I will have to use the attribute names, so cannot make it a generic process. Is that correct?  I want to write a utility that will read the attribute names and crate a child node for the tag of the attribute

Comment: Please show samples of the input and desired output. Your description is very confusing. Every XML has tags, so if the only thing you can tell us about the XML is that it has tags, then we really don't know very much. It's not surprising that all the examples you found use XSLT, because that's the best tool for the job; asking people for a solution using inferior tools will limit the responses you get.

Comment: @Michael Kay - I updated the question with the details of inputs and expected output.

Comment: Would like know the details / reasons for downvote

Comment: I downvoted because the missing information made the question impossible to understand, but you've now fixed that so I've reversed it. Your terminology is still wrong (you're confusing "nodes" and "elements") but with examples of what you really mean, we can handle that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.   Knowing the reason allows me to try not to do the same thing in the future.   I can change the question to replace nodes with elements,  Do you mind explaining the difference? Is node the entire tree / sub-tree and Element is the lowest tag that has a value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't have the time and patience to do a solution using Java DOM interfaces, but here's the XSLT solution in case you change your mind.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]">
     <xsl:copy>{doc('doc2.xml')//DocData[@Name=name(current())]/@Value}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```